# How to download files from a user/password protected web server (user:passw@ip:port)

Tags: esp8266

I need to do a GET request in the form: `user:passw@ip:port/streaming/channels/1/picture`  to capture a still frame from an Ip camera.
Is there a way to do this with the `ESP8266HTTPClient.h` library?

The samples show a GET request as: `http.begin(host,port,url);`
What I need to do is get the `user:passw@` put in before the `host:url`

Comment: You can rewrite your question as a more generic problem (file downloading, password, ports). That way more people will find it.

Answer (score 1):

use the `http.setAuthorization(user, passw)` method.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend whether it's digest or basic authentication.
If former, you have a nice example here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266HTTPClient/examples/DigestAuthorization/DigestAuthorization.ino

and if it's the latter, you can just do something like this: `http.begin("http://user:password@example.com/test.html");`